# Lenovo y500 shows four additional "phantom" external displays

Tags: windows-10, display, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, lenovo-laptop

I have a user with a Lenovo y500 (Windows 10, GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 860M) who's having some odd issues with extra, disabled screens. This user only has (or has ever had) one external monitor (LS24A40xV), but **Display settings** always shows four additional, *disconnected* screens, as though there are four external displays that are turned off or disconnected:

[image: Display settings (external monitor removed)]

(snapshot above was taken while the LS24A40xV external monitor was unplugged)

[image: Wired Displays]

NVIDIA Control Panel shows them as *Analogue Displays*:

[image: Analogue Displays]

There were generic monitors in **Device Manager** > **Monitors** that corresponded to the "Analogue/Wired Displays". I uninstalled all but the laptop display and LS24A40xV, but they all came back on next boot.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Try to also uninstall any "Generic PnP monitor" appearing in Device Manager, and ensure that the latest drivers are installed for the GTX 860M and lntel(R) UHD Graphics.

Comment: Sure.. it sucks.. and I mean no offense.  You asked the question.  Is it actually hurting anything?  This might be a lot of work with little gain.

Comment: @Señor CMasMas - Yeah, it's causing a problem with some software. I didn't mention that part because it wasn't relevant.

Comment: @harrymc - already removed the monitors and they came right back on reboot. Pretty sure user had latest drivers, but I'll double-check.